# Iptables meet with jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, iptables

I met a interesting problem today...
First, I setup a iptable policy like this:

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <jupyter_server_port> -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

that will drop all the packages except those TCP packages who request the jupyter server. After I did this, I could still get response from the server. But the notebook said it couldn't connect to the kernel.

After some googling, I found this document https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/how_ipython_works.html which indicate that the notebook server need to communicate to the ipython kernel through ZeroMQ. So, I disable the second policy and problem solved.

But I still wonder **How I could still keeping the second policy and let the server work just like normal?**